# set combobox's item list based on my query's field

Tags: mysql, vba

I just want to ask if how this code's Item :

```
queryf2 = "SELECT DISTINCT Department FROM tblEmployees"
```

Will display to my combobox, I have a Department field which consist 100 Employees with 5 different departments.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

```
Combo1.RowSource = "SELECT DISTINCT Department FROM tblEmployees;"
```

Comment: Hi Siddharth, i don't have .rowsource in my combo box, i don't know why. Do i need to add something to my project first?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use tag select and edit query like that:

```
queryf2 ="SELECT DISTINCT a.Department, b.name_depart FROM tblEmployees a, departments b WHERE a.department = b.id";
```

You must get two feilds: one feild is value of combobox, other is name of combobox. It's like that

```
<select sql="SELECT DISTINCT a.Department, b.name_depart FROM tblEmployees a, departments b WHERE a.department = b.id"></select>
```